# Python - Need to remove specific value from csv file

Tags: python, csv

I created an CSV file as a sample where I have @handles. (Twitter handles) 
For privacy reasons I need to remove each handle - for example @johnny, @rose, @lucy.

This is what I have so far..... but I'd like to replace the whole handle on each line with an x.

```
file = open('./ExcelTest.csv', 'r')
for line in file:
    #temp = line.find("@")
    line.replace("@"," ")
    print(line)
```

Please help! THANKS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

Regex would certainly help here. Loop through each line and use `re.sub` to get rid of those handles.

```
import re

...    
new_line = re.sub('@[\S]+', '', line)
....
```

Example:

```
In [65]: line = "help me @lucy I'm drowning"

In [66]: re.sub('@[\S]+', '', line)
Out[66]: "help me  I'm drowning"
```

Now, there's that matter of the extra space... hmm... you can chain `re.sub` calls like this:

```
new_line = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', re.sub('@[\S]+', '', line))
```

This is only assuming you don't want extra spaces clustering together once you void the handles.

Answer (score 1):

If your csv file contains all the twitter handles in the same row you may want to use Python's built in [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. The csv module will allow you to read in each row as a Python list and you can simply del elements of the list at a particular index. You can then write back the output to a new file.

```
import csv

file_handler = open('./ExcelTest.csv','r')
file_handler_write = open('./ExcelTest_New.csv','w')

csv_reader = csv.reader(file_handler,delimiter=',')
csv_writer = csv.writer(file_handler_write,delimiter=',')


twitter_handle_col = 2 # set the twitter handle column here

for line in csv_reader:
    del line[twitter_handle_col]
    csv_writer.writerow(line)

file_handler_write.close()
file_handler.close()
```

The columns and delimiters may differ in your particular case but this may be the simplest approach if using a csv.

Input - ExcelTest.csv:

```
a,b,c,d
b,c,d,a
d,c,b,a
```

Output - ExcelTest_New.csv:

```
a,b,d
b,c,a
d,c,a
```

Notice that the third column was deleted.